# How to change the style of escaped symbols such as "\&"?

Tags: symbols, styles

Well, that's pretty it.

I was wondering if there's any way to change the default style of the escaped special characters, because sometimes I find them a bit "out of the line", especially `\&`, which appears slightly bigger and curvier than the usual `&`.

I know it's not that much of importance, but I find it quite unappealing in terms of aesthetics.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Use another font ...

Comment: What's the “usual &”? Can you show an example?

Comment: Fascinating history of the 27th letter, "\`and' per se", http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-1-of-2/ and http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-2-of-2/

Comment: See here for proof of its 27th position, which is how it acquired its name, http://nowiknow.com/and-the-27th-letter-of-the-alphabet/ recited as "x, y, z, and *per se*, and".

Comment: `\&` is just `&` from the current font tex has no control over it. So choosing the shape of & is like choosing the shape of g you just need to pick a font that you like.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes okay, that was interesting indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default,  `\&` is just `&` from the current font tex has no control over it. So choosing the shape of `&` is like choosing the shape of `g`: you just need to pick a font that you like.

However if you really want to change `\&` while keeping the same font then...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\catcode`\&=12 % make & a normal punctuation character not a table cell separator


abc \& xyz   is the same as  abc & xyz.

Like g it shows a lot of variation

g &  \textit{g &}  \textsf{g &}  {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont g &}


But being a command you can redefin it to be anything

0  abc \& xyz

1\renewcommand\&{{\tiny&}}   abc \& xyz

2\renewcommand\&{\raisebox{-.3ex}{&}}   abc \& xyz

3\renewcommand\&{{\large\bfseries AND}}   abc \& xyz


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for! :) (Actually I was pretty sure that escaping a character would change it's shape, well, I see it doesn't. Anyway, this is the perfect answer, modifying shapes and fonts along the same line works greatly!)